# Any local privacy-oriented user authentication for mobile apps?

Tags: authentication, mobile-application, privacy

I'm building an app and I'm being very cautious about the user privacy on the app. I do not want to collect any data. Not even email IDs. Is there any way to do user authentication without email/phone number?

One idea for now is using biometrics on the phone itself. FaceID/TouchID etc. But that brings up challenges wrt syncing their data in case the user wants to use from a different phone. Any workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

You can safely collect as much data as you like *inside* the app, so long as it stays there.

The problem is that you want to *reliably* identify a user account (though not any specific user data) without letting any of that data out. It's become quite common to use hashes (usually SHA256) of email addresses as identifiers, however, if everyone uses the same approach it's like a distributed rainbow table. You can however deploy the usual defence against such attacks by salting your hashes so that they are unique to your service.

If you encrypt the user's data on-device using a key that only they know, and only ever transmit and store encrypted data (i.e. to which you have no access), then they would be able to use the same local identifiers and their key to read the data from a different device. Because data is only ever encrypted and decrypted with the same key you can use symmetric encryption - look at using libsodium to do this.

You might want to consider some kind of 2FA to go with this as otherwise intercepting this identifier could allow unauthorised access.

Depending on the sensitivity of the traffic, you may want to try to hide meta-information such as connection dates, times, and volumes, so you could get the app to generate random data to hide the real data within.

Disclaimer - I Am Not A Cryptographer! I recommend you ask for more qualified responses on https://security.stackexchange.com.